# Scala.js: Selecting and manipulating generated SVG

Tags: jquery, scala, dom, svg, scala.js

I'm struggling with something seemingly simple.

Using Scaja.JS, I have generated some SVG with the ScalaTags library.

I now wish to manipulate the SVG elements using events:

```
circ.onclick = { e: dom.MouseEvent => ... }
```

Specifically, I want to select all elements of a certain class and then toggle some class attributes on them.

I tried the Scala.js JQuery binding. While I can retrieve selections with it, I cannot manipulate the selected elements (set classes etc). This seems to be a fundamental problem of SVG being a different kind of DOM which cannot be manipulated with JQuery.

Next, I tried the low level DOM API. This gets me the selection:

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName("myClass").foreach { node =>  ... }
```

I now struggle with manipulating attributes of `node`. I can access them but I cannot set them, as `node.attributes.setNamedItem(...)` requires a `raw.Attr` argument which I have trouble creating, There is no constructor to set the `name` of the `Attr`.

Also, going for the low level API is quite inconvenient. I'd prefer to get a selection of some class that is easier to manipulate, e.g. `Element`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The concept of a name is an html thing, not an SVG thing. The nodes are, however elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no constructor for `Attr` in the javascript DOM api, either. Attempting to evaluate `new Attr()` in javascript will result in an "Illegal constructor" TypeError.  You can however create attributes using `document.createAttribute(name: String)`.

Although `getElementsByClassName` is returning a NodeList, each item will actually be an Element (you will have to downcast this with pattern matching or similar). From a `dom.Element` you can invoke `setAttribute(name: String, value: String)` which may be more convenient than manually creating `Attr`s at such a low level.

Also, jQuery's ability to select elements of the dom using expressions has now been mostly built into the DOM using `document.querySelectorAll`.  You might try something like `svgDocument.querySelectorAll(".foo").map(_.asInstanceOf[dom.raw.SVGElement])
.foreach { _.setAttribute("someAttribute", "newValue") }`.

Of course- to treat a NodeList as a Scala Collection will require `import org.scalajs.dom.ext._` to bring the implicits into scope, but it looks as though you're already doing that.

Comment: Works perfectly! It's still a bit verbose, but Scala makes it easy to write some JQuery-like convenience methods.